# How to cover UIAlertView with another view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using UIAlertView as a holder of tableview. When I click on some row, I need to show some information about item and would like to show another view for these purposes. I can hide uialertview and show my viewcontroller.view, but then when I go back and show alertview again, it is shown with animation, which is not pretty enough. So I need some trick to not dismiss my alertview before showing another view, so when I remove view, user can immediately see alertview. Any trick to add UIView above alertview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should reconsider the way you are displaying information to the user. You should avoid modal dialogs (except when *absolutely* required). Having more than one modal dialog open at once is 1) annoying and 2) confusing for the user.

You should probably display the UITableView inside a regular view and then push another view for the detailed information. This is the customary way of doing what you want, and I would advise you not to deviate from the standard way of doing things, lest you confuse your users. Let Apple teach people how to use the device, and if you follow Apple's commands, then users will almost automatically know how to use your application.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use the `UIAlertView` like this. It is supposed to completely take over the attention of the user, i.e. to bused "modally". The only extension I have seen beyond two buttons is `UITextField`s, like Apple's App Store sign-in.

A simple solution is to make your own view, which gives you all the flexibility you need.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1) is the relevant section of Apple's iOS Human Interface Guidelines. (Search for "Alerts".)

Comment: Your link points to a file on your HD which the rest of us can't access